# UITabelView shows empty but displays data after click

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have two tableviewcells one for parent and one for the child I am populating both using my conditions but they are not showing data but blank labels only. but as soon as I click on a cell it displays data but not properly.

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let parentCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DaleelDetailChildsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DaleelDetailChildsTableViewCell

        let siblingCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DaleelDetailSiblingTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DaleelDetailSiblingTableViewCell


//        
//        if (self.detailPerson?.childrens.count)! < 1 {
//            self.isSiblingButton = true
//          self.btnSiblings.setImage(UIImage(named:"FamilyLeftPressed"), for: .normal)
//        }

        if self.isSiblingButton{
            if indexPath.row == 0
            {
                parentCell.configuration(name: (self.detailPerson?.fatherName)!, profilePicture: "", myCell: false)
                return parentCell

            }else{

                if self.detailPerson?.name == (self.detailPerson?.siblings[indexPath.row-1].name)!
                {
                    siblingCell.configuration(person: (self.detailPerson?.siblings)!, tag: indexPath.row - 1, myCell: true )
                }else{
                    siblingCell.configuration(person: (self.detailPerson?.siblings)!, tag: indexPath.row - 1, myCell: false )
                }   
                return siblingCell
            }


        }else{

            if indexPath.row == 0
            {
                parentCell.configuration(name: (self.detailPerson?.name)!, profilePicture: (self.detailPerson?.profilePictureSquare)!, myCell: true)
                return parentCell
            }else{

                siblingCell.configuration(person: (self.detailPerson?.childrens)!, tag: indexPath.row - 1, myCell: false )

                return siblingCell
            }


        }


    }
```

`

Comment: I need to see implementation of methods configuration() in DaleelDetailChildsTableViewCell and DaleelDetailSiblingTableViewCell and how do you define UI of these cells?

Comment: thos functios are just assigning values to labels and images of cells. e.g cell.label.text = value from controller

Comment: try to set background color of cell to white color and cell.label.textColor to black